# How to add sorting in drupal pagination result

Tags: drupal, sorting, drupal-6, pagination

I am new in drupal and I am using drupal 6. I have a listing of record with pagination. Now I have to add sorting in result but It is not possible to alter the query for get sorted result. So Is there any way so I can modify result fetching from query and then modify Pagination lisiting.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know if you are using Views or how you are sorting your 'listing'.  Are you just using the default frontpage?  Without more context this question is not answerable

Comment: Hi, I  am using views module in drupal 6 and I have set the sorting, relationship option from admin panel for particular view. And listing of record is coming in front-end . Now I have to sorted the listing but sorting is not possible from altering query.I have to add some conditions in php code so is it possible that after sorting i can manage my pagination according that. thanks